# Standard Container Size For Mobile Canvas?

Tags: website-design, mobile-application, human-interface-guideline

I am creating a mobile design in **Figma** and my selected frame size is *428 x 926 px* (for I phone 13 pro max). I want a **container** to achieve a proper grid system, can you please tell me what should be the size of my container inside the canvas?

Answer (score 2):

When you select the standard frame size, it's already in the safe display zone so that you can use the whole space for the grid system. These two resources can freshen up your knowledge and remove any other related confusions about grids & guides.

[the-grid-system-building-a-solid-design-layout](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/the-grid-system-building-a-solid-design-layout)

[designing-with-grid-based-approach](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/04/designing-with-grid-based-approach/)